# RemoteApp Web Client : Command line parameters

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, remoteapp

I am using 2016 server to publish windows application. 
Clients will use a html 5 browser to access the applications. 
Everything working fine, but i would like to access one of the published directly (ie openign on a new tab on the browser)

My questions are :

1. Is there an URL which gives access directly to a published application ?
2. If so can we pass some comman line parameters ?

Thanks for your help